# how to access data from inside a method

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

I'm new to vue.js. I'm starting to migrate my angularjs app.
I'm using vue cli to generate a new simple-webpack project.
This creates a new webpack+vueLoader project.
Everything went smoothly but now I have an issue.
on my @click event I want to change my data but I can't access the object.
'this' is not the data instance.

What am I missing here?

```
<template>
    <input type="radio" name="account-type" @click="setAccountType(item.id)"/><span>{{item.name}}</span>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
     data() {
        return { accountType: null
     },
     methods: { setAccountType: (typeId) => this.accountType = typeId
  }
</script>
```

this is not the data instance as expected and thus ui not updated.
In vuejs doc i can see just addressing this is sufficient while in a method:
[vue js doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers)

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot use an arrow function to refer to `this` inside a Vue instance to get Vue instance data because `this` refers to `window`, the correct ES6 syntax is:

```
 setAccountType(typeId){
   this.accountType = typeId
 }
```

JSFiddle with Arrow function: https://jsfiddle.net/zxqohh0L/

JSFiddle with non arrow ES6 function: https://jsfiddle.net/zxqohh0L/1/

You can still use arrow functions inside the methods themselves.

Comment: outstanding answer. thank you very much for the effort

Comment: Very good explanation, I was digging to access the data inside a function with arrow function. Your answer really fixed my issue and also help to understand better.

Comment: Thank you very much! two hours wasted on this. It was driving me crazy.

Comment: It's too bad that using an arrow function completely breaks data binding, and you don't get a meaningful error message about it either. You'd think that the Vue instance would check for this and issue a warning.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work because i was using an arrow function, as you said.